# laravel 7.x one to many

Tags: laravel, one-to-many

I have in my project laravel 7.x issue
eloquent one to many relationship
my model **sallat** is :

```
 public function sallproducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(sallat_product::class);
}
```

and the **sallat_products** model is:

```
  public function sallats()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(sallat::class);
}
```

and my input method in controller is:

```
$sallats = new sallat();
$sallats->full_total = $request->full_total;
$sallats->save();
$sall = new sallat_product();
$sall->name_product = $request->name_product;
$sall->total = $request->total;
$sall->quantity =  $request->quantity;
$sall->price = $request->price;
$sall->sale = $request->sale;
$sallats->sallproducts()->save($sall);
return "done";
```

or I can do this:

```
$sallats->sallproducts()->save($sall);


     return "done";
```

then I tried to test the post request on postman

```
{
"full_total":87997,
"arr":
[
    {
        "name_product":"سيتامول",
        "quantity":222,
        "total":299,
        "price":100,
        "sale":"10+2"
    }
]
```

}

I want to insert multi records in one request in this way above,
and i have this error on postman :

> *SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sallat_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `sallat_products` (`name_product`, `total`, `quantity`, `price`, `sale`, `sallat_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 18, 2021-07-11 02:51:59, 2021-07-11 02:51:59))*

this is sallat_products migration :

```
 $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('id_sallat')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('id_sallat')->references('id')->on('sallats');
        $table->string('name_product');
        $table->integer('total');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->string('sale');
        $table->timestamps();
```

and sallats migration:

```
  $table->id();
        $table->integer('full_total');
        $table->timestamps();
```

so what should i do
can anyone help me please to solute this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `sallat_products` migration it should be:

```php
$table->bigInteger('sallat_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('sallat_id')->references('id')->on('sallats');
```

instead of `id_sallat` to match Laravel conventions.

Alternatively, you can specify the name of this column as the second arguments to `hasMany` and `belongsTo` in your relationships.

Comment: ok what should I do to insert multi records in one request like json above?